# Constructing your own oil/water sprayer

Tags: oil

I have used Pam with great success, but I'd like to build my own oil sprayer so that I can control what kinds of oil I want to use. I also do a lot of break baking and the ability to build a water sprayer will also be helpful. How have you built your own homemade oil sprayer?

Answer (score 10):

As someone who's currently trying to construct a sprayer for a sort of performance art thing, my recommendation is -- don't bother.

There are plenty of pump sprayers available at kitchen stores that you can fill and use.

There are two basic styles -- the ones where you [squeeze a trigger and stuff shoots out with each squeeze like some cleaning products](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H88PCU), and the ones that you [pump up first and then press the button to release like an aerosol can](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0048PTGLW).

I like the trigger ones for water (for keeping near the grill to deal with flareups).  I like the aerosol-like ones for oils, as I get a finer spray for popcorn, and I can still lay down a decent coating in a pan for cooking.

I *do not* like the [stainless steel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004SPZV) [aerosol sprayers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009V4CA) -- you want a clear one, so you can see how much oil there is in the container, and you don't overfill, as you need to leave quite a bit of space for the pressurized air.

You should also look for ones where the tube goes deep into the container -- if it stops 1" from the bottom, that means you can't use it when the oil or liquid is low, and you have to refill it more often.

...

I should also note that Pam and other spray oils have an additive in them that makes it so they won't bead up after you spray it, which means it'll coat things better ... misting it with oil works pretty well, but it'll start beading up if you leave it after doing it.

Comment: Interesting about a clear container. I like that - hadn't seen one yet.

Comment: @zanlok : yeah, once you switch to one, you won't want to go back to the many stainless steel ones.  Yes, oil should be kept away from light, but I just keep the container in a cabinet.

Comment: After looking around a bit, Amazon only has only a few (3) clear misters, and one has no reviews. If you don't mind, I'd love to hear a recommendation if you most like a particular model?

Comment: @zanlok : I haven't used enough different ones to know, I'm still on my first non-stainless one, and it's held up well for two years with almost daily usage (of amateur usage, not in a restaurant).  I'll have to check the brand when I get home.

Comment: @zanlok : oh, right ... I never posted a response ... there's unfortunately no markings on the container, but it looks like [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Maftfer-Bourgeat-Matfer-Oil-Sprayer/dp/B0048PTGLW/) ... and I've never tried the filter on it, but yes, there's something funny at the end of the uptake tube.

Comment: @Joe - Thanks :)  I'll have to get one; we're overdue for a new kitchen toy.

Comment: @Joe Stainless steel container has advantage of keeping oil hidden from sun while clear container does not have but has advantage of letting me see the level of oil?

Comment: Another thing: when it comes to oil spray bottle, I see people complain about it soon starts to spray stream of oil instead of mist. Do you have any tips on how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @Boris_yo : that's a sign it's not pressurized well enough.  If it sprays for a bit, then switches to stream, make sure you've left enough head space for the air; if it continues to give problems, fill it to only 1/2 way to the 'max fill' line.  (and this is why I like the clear containers; just keep 'em in a cabinet to keep em 'out of sunlight)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to build one, exactly. You can buy an oil sprayer that you can load with whatever oil you want to use. I've used this one with much success: [http://www.amazon.com/Misto-M100S-Gourmet-Brushed-Aluminum/dp/B00004SPZV/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004SPZV)

Comment: Yes - I love these. Saves you some money in the long term so you can use bigger/cheaper oil containers, but use less oil, and not buying aerosols is nice.

Comment: @zanlok What is the disadvantage of aerosol oil sprays exactly? Is it from convenience or health standpoint?

Comment: Just meant that a refillable sprayer saves you having to buy lots of aerosol containers and saves cupboard space. If other concerns exist, those would be secondary.