# Misto nozzle leaks

Tags: equipment

While trying to clean my Misto, the nozzle came off.  I pushed it back on, but it leaks and  now I can't get any pressure when I pump.  How do I replace the spray nozzle so it fits tightly?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get any pressure, it's something more than just the nozzle at the end of the tube ... it's something deeper in the mechanism (triggering the over-pressure release), or an issue with the gasket and threaded top.

Try turning your sprayer over for a few seconds, then back right-side up and pump to pressurize the sprayer quickly about 2x more than your typically would, to intentionally over-pressurize it.  Then listen for a hiss, and look for anywhere that might have bubbling or other signs of a leak.

If it's in the gasket, you can try cranking down the plastic ring tighter, turning the gasket over, or replacing the gasket.  If it's coming from somewhere else, you likely have to [replace it.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11401/67); they typically last 2-4 years (I've had some last longer, lots of people have reported failures after a few months, so read online reviews before picking a brand)