# Lemon juice sprayer/container

Tags: equipment, lemon, containers

I often zest up my food with lemon juice and I usually have squeezed juice in the fridge in a jar because I like it pre squeezed, with pulp and seeds removed.  However, a jar is not an ideal container for distributing lemon juice over food because it's hard to get an even coverage, rather a few spots of intense concentration.

Are there better containers or perhaps even some form of sprayer for spraying lemon juice over food evenly?  I was hesitant to use a regular water spray bottle because I thought the juice, despite being strained for pulp, still might have small pieces that could clog the tube.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/11404/67

Answer (score 2):

I personally use squeeze bottles to store my citrus juices, including pre-strained lemon juice.  They're nearly identical to [these versions from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RGWGTGE) (though more colorful) which I like because they have a built-in cap to keep the container sealed.  There are a number of other styles sold, but know that most don't include caps.  The small tips make them easy to dispense precisely; give them a quick squeeze over your food (or even wave them around and let the drops fall where they may) and you'd get controlled, relatively even distribution.

I wouldn't recommend them for long-term storage, as plastic can mess with flavors over an extended time, but lemon juice gets acrid after a week or so anyway.  You could try out a spray bottle, but these have minimal moving parts and they're dishwasher-safe.

Answer (score 2):

I would like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0070ASMF8).

[image: 1]

The two ounce size would be just right for the juice of one lemon. There would be no need to wash the sprayer between lemons as long as you never used it for anything else. In the fridge it would preserve the juice as well as anything. Once and while spray some hot water through it and shake some soapy water in the bottle.

Joe commented that it would be a good idea to strain any pulp out of the juice before putting it in this type of bottle. Absolutely, I imagine would quickly clog the sprayer otherwise.

Now I want one. On Amazon they come in 1, 2 and 4 ounce sizes in packs of 1, 6 or 12. The reviews are pretty good too.

Comment: You may need to strain the juice before putting it in the bottle, so you don't end up clogging the suction hose with pulp.  Some of the sprayers sold for oil have a filter at the end, but they tend to be much larger.  (although, the ones that you pressure with air need 1/3 to 1/2 empty so there's sufficient head space for the air)

Comment: @Joe Excellent point. I'm going to add that to the answer.

Comment: This is a good idea; I use these to dispense other things (like pastis) in very fine amounts. These things are pretty cheap ($2-3 each) and readily available in the US at organic food markets and co-ops. Sometimes they're behind a counter in the supplements/herbal remedies section. The only thing I wonder is whether they'd dispense enough juice; each pump produces only a *very* fine misting.

Comment: @logophobe I'm adding one to my next Amazon order just to see.