# How to make homemade cooking spray

Tags: oil

I think I tried to put oil in a spray bottle before and I don't recall it working very well. how can you make a cooking spray that will not gum up a spray bottle?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11401/constructing-your-own-oil-water-sprayer/11403#11403

Comment: Why not just buy Pam spray at the store? I know its a mixture of oil and aerosol, just dont know how the process goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For several years, I've been putting canola in a plastic squeeze spray bottle and using that.
I do not recommend 'vegatable' oil, which in the USA is usually 100% soy oil and I have found that it gums up and can leave a difficult to clean residue

Yes, my system can apply too much and do so unevenly too. just use a paper towel to wipe off ecess and even out.

Far cheaper with canola priced at about $5 per US gallon versus 8 oz of generic aerosol spray at $1.99